# site.master tells pages to wait loading...but site kind of still comes up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Aside from it not being "recommended" we needed to do this for a specific project.  Basically I've got a site master page that is displays a "Please wait while loading..." `div` to not display a page until it has been loaded.  Reason being is we have many 3rd party tools that are quite slow to load.

In any event we have something to this effect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#msg").show();
    $('#pageBody').css('opacity', 0);
    $(window).load(function () {
        $("#msg").hide();
        $('#pageBody').css('opacity', 1);
    });
</script>
```

We also set a timeout in the case that something doesn't load, we want the page to come back...

`setTimeout('$("#pageBody").css("opacity", 1)', 1000);`

The html is as simple as this snippet:

```
<body id="pageContainer">
    <div id="msg" style="text-align:center;font-weight: bold;">
        Loading, please wait...<br/>
        <img src="/Images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading please wait..."/>
    </div>
    <div id="pageBody">
    </div>
</body>
```

The div id=pageBody is a container for all my .aspx pages that use this site master.  The issue is when I go to one of these pages, it seems that I see the `loading please wait...` but then I still see the page for say 1/2 a second but then it goes away and comes back as fully loaded..its a bit noticeable to the user so the experience isn't as great.

I'm not really a front end developer so I am not certain if I am doing something wrong.  Should I go to my .aspx pages and be doing anything in the jquery there...I was under the assumption that the site.master would handle everything.

Comment: Set the appropriate CSS for the `#msg` (`display: block;`) and `#pageBody` (`opacity: 0;`) elements, instead of having to run `$("#msg").show(); $('#pageBody').css('opacity', 0);`. Then all you need is the `$(window).load` handler. That way, by default the correct things are hidden/shown as the page is rendered, and only when you want to hide/show things (`$(window).load`) will they be correct

Comment: @Ian can you post it as an example, I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  The effect i am looking for is the page starts off with `Loading, please wait...` (which is the div `msg`.  Once the windowload is ready it simply hides this message and brings the page back using the opacity.

Comment: @Ian I got you...looks to be okay can you post it and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the appropriate CSS for the `#msg` element (**display: block**) and `#pageBody` element (**opacity: 0**), instead of running `$("#msg").show(); $('#pageBody').css('opacity', 0);`. Then, all you need is the `$(window).load` handler.

That way, by default, the correct things are hidden/shown as the page is rendered, and only when you want to hide/show things (`$(window).load`) will they be correct.

Here's how I'd set it up (of course, some of it is for demo):

HTML -

```
<div id="msg">
    Loading, please wait...
</div>
<div id="pageBody">
    <div>HERE'S</div>
    <div>SOME</div>
    <div>CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
#msg {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
}

#pageBody {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

JS -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Simulate some time before everything's loaded
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#msg").fadeOut(function () {
            // Wait for #msg to fade out before fading in #pageBody
            $("#pageBody").animate({
                opacity: "1.0"
            }, 800);
        });
    }, 1500);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/X7nBN/

Comment: Nice I really like the touch of the div fading out and the page coming in...great job.

Answer (score 1):

Create the overlay directly in the HTML using CSS instead of having Javascript show the overlay.

It's basically the same setup you have except the overlay will be visible always and only hidden when the page is fully loaded.

You would have something like this on your header:

```
<!-- jQuery assumed to be loaded prior to this code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(document).load(function(){
            $('#msg').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

So, basically you do not have to use display:none or opacity:0 or visibility:hidden for your page. Just put the overlay directly over it, it should be covered completely. Then, when the page is loaded just remove or hide the overlay to show the webpage.